# Exception inside a multiprocessing.Pool().map halts execution

Tags: python, multiprocessing

my `multiprocessing.Pool(5).map(func, iterable)` does not return because one process is raising an exception. How can I continue execution after this exception raises?

I hoped moving to `map_async` would solve this (maybe with the `_error_callback`), but I had the same issue there.

Example code:

### x.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from os import getpid
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    print(x**2, f'Hi Im {getpid()}')
    if not x:
        raise Exception(f'bla {x}')


pool = mp.Pool(5)
res = pool.map(f, range(5))
print(res)
```

---

Output:

```
0 Hi Im 15701
1 Hi Im 15702
4 Hi Im 15703
9 Hi Im 15704
16 Hi Im 15705
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "./x.py", line 8, in f
    raise Exception(f'bla {x}')
Exception: bla 0
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./x.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(res.get())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 768, in get
    raise self._value
Exception: bla 0
```

If I remove the offending process, everything works fine: (i.e. run with `range(1,5)`)

Comment: `range(5)` is 0-4.  `0` will pass your check (`not x`)

Comment: yes, this the core of the question. This is the offending process. What I don't get is how to continue execution after it raised its exception

Comment: Catch the exception in the function (try\except)

Comment: Not my function. This is just an example code, the real `f` is `paramiko.connect()` which I don't mean to change + I want a handle from the `mp` side

Comment: You can try wrapping that function in your own function that catches errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using multiprocessing.Pool with exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814142/using-multiprocessing-pool-with-exception-handling)

Comment: @RandomDavis No, because I want to understand why the execution stops. I found that using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` works much better, but I'm not sure why, yet

Comment: @CIsForCookies well you're trying to create a list of the outputs of 5 processes, and one crashes - so, the list can't be built, and the `map` function doesn't just stick a `None` in place of the result like `imap` does, so it just stops executing and throws an exception. It's just that that's how it is defined to work - you chose a method that doesn't handle exceptions how you want, but there are ones (like `imap`) that do. What do you want to have happen instead of execution stopping due to the unhandled exception? You imply you don't want `None` or to handle the exception.

Comment: I expect, like any other process, that if an exception is thrown, I'll exit with an error code, not be stuck, waiting forever

Comment: @RandomDavis BTW, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814142/using-multiprocessing-pool-with-exception-handling is not helpful. both answers still get stuck (unlike `ThreadPool`)

Answer (score 1):

AS you can see the python documentation on multiprocessing Pool:

**Warning
multiprocessing.pool objects have internal resources that need to be properly managed (like any other resource) by using the pool as a context manager or by calling close() and terminate() manually. Failure to do this can lead to the process hanging on finalization.
Note that is not correct to rely on the garbage colletor to destroy the pool as CPython does not assure that the finalizer of the pool will be called (see object.**del**() for more information).**

It clearly says if you don't use context managers or close() or terminate then your program got stuck inside.

```
from os import getpid
import multiprocessing as mp


def f(x):
    print(x**2, f'Hi Im {getpid()}')
    if not x:
        raise Exception(f'bla_{x}')


with mp.Pool(5) as pool:
    res = pool.map(f, range(5))
print(res)
```

Now if you run this code then it will not stuck and it will be executed correctly.

Also if you don't want to use the context manager then you need to close the pool manually by using

```
pool.close()
```

After doing so you are properly managing the pool resources.

Comment: @CIsForCookies Can you mark this answer as correct if it resolves your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The `Pool.imap` solution referred to in a comment is *one way* but only conveniently allows for target functions with a single function. I believe the following is more flexible:

If instead you use the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class from the `concurrent.futures` module with the `submit` method, which returns a `Future` instance, you have greater control over each submission's result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from os import getpid
import concurrent.futures

def f(x):
    print(x**2, f'Hi Im {getpid()}')
    if not x:
        raise Exception(f'bla {x}')
    return x**2 # let's return a value just for fun


def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(5) as pool:
        futures = [pool.submit(f, i) for i in range(5)]
        for future in futures: # wait for all "jobs" to complete ...
            try:
                result = future.result() # ... by retrieving the result, which could be an exception
                print('result of calling f:', result)
            except Exception as e:
                print('exception found in result:', e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
0 Hi Im 12996
1 Hi Im 5152
4 Hi Im 11160
9 Hi Im 12996
exception found in result: bla 0
16 Hi Im 5152
result of calling f: 1
result of calling f: 4
result of calling f: 9
result of calling f: 16
```

Comment: I think ClsforCookies is asking the reason why his program is not halting with some error code.

Comment: This looks very similar to the actual implementation of multiprocessing. This will work, but it is not what I'm looking for (as I already have a working solution using `ThreadPool`). What I'm looking for is the reason for the weird `mp` behaviour. Why does it get stuck mid-execution?

Comment: I know on Windows you need to run the process creation code within a if \_\_name\_\_ == '\_\_main\_\_': block.

Comment: And I certainly read the question differently. When using `pool.map`, as soon as it processes the result from a "job' that raised an exception, the ballgame is over and you can't continue. My understanding is that was the problem and my code overcomes it. And it is halting -- with the bla 0 exception.

Comment: On my desktop, when I put the the last 3 lines in a if \_\_name__ == '\_\_main__':  block, the progam throws a `bla 0` exception and terminates.